# C# inventory updating stock

Tags: c#, database, inventory-management

I am building an app with a SQL Server database. I have a main table of products (`tblProducts`) with a column that holds the quantity in hand (`quantity`). Another table holds the orders (`tblOrders`) that come from the supplier.

When an order comes in, I add the order to my database (`tblOrders`) and then I edit `tblProducts` to add to the quantity column the new received product. 
As far, everything is good.

My question: after let's say 1 year of many many orders, with a lot of edits in quantity, do you guys, periodically check all orders to check if the quantity in main table `tblProducts` is correct ? Or do I just assume that it is always correct?

What procedures do you use for updating this kind of database? Do you sum all orders every time when you need quantity in hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't materialize the count in stock, if this can be queried from the orders. Simple as that, nothing to check periodically or whenever, because it is always right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really up to how you want to implement it.

- Trusting that the values will always check out (with adequate testing to ensure only stable code will see production) is the **easiest and the fastest** way, but might be vulnerable to data corruption, and thus, not that recommended.
- Always summing up the orders is the **safest way** and *correct* way, but will become increasingly slower as the size of your tables grow. If this is not an issue for you, then this is the **recommended** option.
- What I consider a good **intermediate method** is to have a separate `tblProductLogs` table which stores the stock of an item at a specific timestamp. You can sum the inventory at set periods (daily, hourly, up to you), and when you want to retrieve the current inventory stock you only need to sum the values that were registered **after** the last log entry for that item, saving you query time. This could be made more safe if update operations were disabled on the log table, since you won't need to modify the entries there. This is **faster** than the second option, and **somewhat more stable** than the first.